# Azure Logic App by scripting, rather the Portal designer

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-logic-apps

Is it possible to edit a Logic App from terminal/cmd?

I have the json code for the logicapp. So I'm wondering if there is a way to edit or put the json code to Azure Portal from terminal, something like sqlcmd which can be used to modify database in Azure.

The goal is to use Azure Portal least possible.

Answer (score 0):

ARM templates. You create a json template defining your logic app and other services needed by it, and then you can use Powershell or Azure CLI or already defined task in the Azure Release Pipelines, to actually release your logic app.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-create-deploy-azure-resource-manager-templates

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use following command to modify and update logic app

```
Set-AzureRmLogicApp

PS C:\>Set-AzureRmLogicApp -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup11" -Name "LogicApp17" -State "Enabled" -AppServicePlan "ServicePlan01" -DefinitionFilePath "d:\workflows\Definition17.json" -ParameterFilePath "d:\workflows\Parameters17.json"
```

There are some examples in the link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.logicapp/Set-AzureRmLogicApp?view=azurermps-6.13.0

Comment: can I run "Set-AzureRmLogicApp" from command prompt? or only from power shell?

Comment: you can run from command prompt but I guess you still have to call powershell first
check this question
https://superuser.com/questions/1080239/run-powershell-command-from-cmd

Comment: @AmirAliWafai if it answers your question then could you please accept the answer.

Comment: I'm working with that. If I make it work, I will accept the answer. Right now I'm working with "az group deployment create" so that I don't have o use powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Well...why do you want to do this?  You can, but it's much easier to use a designer in most cases.  It's not really analogous to SQL.

If just want to avoid the Portal, you can use Visual Studio to edit Logic Apps and deploy by PowerShell.

For clarity, if you are asking this because of the other situation, stop and fix that problem first.  Your problem there is *not caused by the Portal*.